# What date API should I use to avoid GC pauses?

Tags: java, performance, date, datetime, algorithmic-trading

I am writing a solution for HFT ( High-Frequency Trading ), which processes the messages that contain dates, I need to work with date in each message.

Famous date libraries - Joda-Time, Time4J, Date4J and Java 8 date API have immutable classes that bring much garbage. The result is GC pauses.

Are there libraries to avoid any garbage without writing my own implementation?
Any best practices?

Comment: By "process dates", you mean "parse string date" ? What object or date type do you need, is a timestamp (simple `long`) an option ?

Comment: Bear in mind, there are very good reasons why they're implemented as immutable. By solving one problem you'll be introducing another. Have you profiled your code and found date/time objects to be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Not use Java? :)

Comment: Actually, the goal is to get current time in nanoseconds and format it and vice versa. I am able to create my own implementation but maybe there are libraries

Comment: You could probably save some object creations. For example assuming you receive an iso timestamp in UTC: `long nanoOfDay = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(input).get(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY)`. That will save the creation of a few objects vs. creating an `Instant` object. But as pointed out above, profiling your app to make sure that the GC activity is due to the date objects is an important first step.

Comment: This question could be a better fit for Software Recommendations SE.

Comment: Which format of your timestamps do you need, always in UTC, too?

Comment: Background of my question before is: If you only need a very specialized solution then you can elaborate one without creating too many objects (mainly working with java-primitives). Major reasons to use a time library are flexibility (i.e. different format patterns), i18n-support and support for timezone calculations. If you can live without such features then the specialized approach might be fine enough but at least you will surely need the [gregorian calendar algorithm](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/blob/master/core/src/main/java/net/time4j/base/GregorianMath.java)